# Rosrun did not work with hello world program in C++

Tags: c++, ros

I try to run ROS packages on Windows 11. I install ROS on Windows using [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) . I tried to create my 1st ROS package using [this tutorial](https://decrypthere.blogspot.com/2020/05/hello-world-project-in-ros-on-windows-10.html). However, when I ran ROS command "rosrun hello_world_pkg hello_world_node", I got the error "Couldn't find executable named hello_world_node". The tutorial to build a ros package in Windows describes if I get that error I could resolve it using devel and setup.bat. I followed the instruction but that could not resolve the error. There is no compilation error in the code. I found the hello_world_node.exe file on the path c:\opt\ros\noetic\catkin_ws\build\hello_world_pkg. If I run hello_world_node from this path it ran well. However, I am unable to execute the file using the rosrun command.

It would be great if someone help me to figure out the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're trying to run ROS on Windows 11. Presently support for ROS1 distros is iffy on Windows as it was mainly meant to target Linux. ROS2 does target Windows as well as Linux, however, the most recent distros specifically are only built for Windows 10.

You have a catkin workspace so the assumption is that you're using ROS1. So your only real solution is to either use Windows 10 and try to get it working there, or even better use Linux.